# Subversion: Merging: 403 Forbidden in response to options (Why would it need access to an upper level folder in the repository?)

Tags: svn, merge

We have the trunk of out project at `http://server/repositiory/project/trunk` and a branch at `http://server/repositiory/project/branches/branch`.

I only have access to `http://server/repositiory/project` and below. I don't have access to `http://server/repositiory` and I normally don't need access at that level as everything in our project is below `http://server/repositiory/project`.

But on attempting to reintegrate the `http://server/repositiory/project/branches/branch` branch into the trunk (with Tortoise SVN) I'm receiving the following error:

```
Error: Server sent unexpected return value (403 Forbidden) in response to OPTIONS   
Error: request for 'http://server/repository'
```

Which I understand the meaning of except why would it need to access that level when everything we work with is at a lower level under `http://server/repositiory/project` ?

Is this normal SVN behavior?
Is it possible to perform this merge without changing the permissions on the server (we don't have administrative access to the server and changing this involves some bureaucracy)?
If this is normal behavior what are the minimal permissions needed at the `http://server/repositiory` level to perform the merge?

Comment: I worked around this by merging folders at a lower level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not trying to get the OPTIONS of the highest level of your SVN server. It is just trying to tell you that the SVN server came back and said that you do not have the rights to the OPTIONS command.

When setting up SVN permissions, you can explicitly set which svn commands a user can have access to. Likely, you have access to GET and UPDATE, but not OPTIONS.